# The Com­pre­hen­sive LaTeX Sym­bol List update

Tags: symbols

I have been using the 9 November 2009 `The Com­pre­hen­sive LaTeX Sym­bol List` since it came out but I was just wondering if there would be an update to this list. I presume, not sure, that a few things might have changed from its creation. Maybe new math fonts have been created or new symbols developed here that would merit inclusion in the list or a new list, say `The TeX.SX Comprehensive List`.

Comment: Any update should of course include U+1F4A9

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is U+1F4A9 a maths symbol, a text symbol, or a "turn your back on this one, it's not very nice" sort of symbol?

Comment: @wasteofspace I think it should be a math symbol, I'd love to see a refereed math article using it as a variable name.  (The Unicode name is pile of poo)

Comment: regardless of opinions from @DavidCarlisle, the list should *definitely* have U+1D400-U+1D7FF added, as well as much else added to unicode as part of the stix effort, but there's still some more work to be done on the latex support for the stix fonts, so i'd hope that could be completed before such additions.

Comment: I'd include the symbols from fontawesome, I mean, they're awesome!

Comment: Anyone know what the licence is? (Maybe David Carlisle?) I can't seem to find it in the source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there has been a number of updates since.

Comment: @Werner I don't think that makes it off-topic. The question could be answered by explaining how one can see the updates in each version. (E.g. maybe [this link to announcements](https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/pkg/comprehensive)?)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: The addition of the second answer just stating that "there's a new version" could generalize to a new answer every time there's an update. That's what the question asks, so I don't think there's much value. It's similar to a package update that solves a problem, in my opinion.

Comment: @Werner I think the right question is “how can a user know what has changed in the comprehensive symbols list?” IMO it's natural for a user to want to know what's new since any given version, and that's not an off-topic question (at least, if there's a way to find out, which I hope there is).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List of 9 November 2009 list 5913 symbols, whereas the [updated version in CTAN of 30 November 2015](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) contain more than double: 14032 symbols.

Answer (score 1):

The [latest version](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/) is on CTAN.